# Bootstrap grid config

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, grid

i cant find the correct config to this config in bootstrap 3 ...

[image: Bootstrap 3 grid config]

i have this input field but i cant put the image in that position

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
            <input size="16" class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre" required placeholder="Tu nombre completo">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
            <input size="16" class="form-control" type="email" name="correo" required placeholder="Tu email">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="agregar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Agregar usuario sugerido</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="agregar">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Agregar usuario sugerido</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="agregar">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Agregar usuario sugerido</button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
       Image here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should have another look at the grid docu. Nesting is an solid option furthermore you do not need to use col-sm-6 combined with col-md-6 only use the smaller one if the values are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are making it a little too complicated, see my codepen. When working with Bootstrap think big to small. It helps you develop a layout and then work your way down to smaller things.

Hope this helps! :)

http://codepen.io/sequential/pen/egxbbK

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 tier1">
    <div class="smBox"></div>
    <div class="smBox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 tier1">
     <div class="lgBox"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem Ipz!